# QT adding to qmake file in Netbeans

Tags: linux, qt, netbeans, makefile

How can I add definitions to the qmake file NetBeans uses to build QT projects?

For example, to use `#include <QDomDocument>` the qmake file needs:

```
QT += xml
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the .pro file found in `/nbproject` is auto-generated, making modifications there will not work.

Instead, within NetBeans follow these steps:

1. Right-click the project name in the left-side file directory and select **properties** at the bottom
2. Select **Build > Qt**
3. Scroll to the bottom and select **Custom Definitions**
4. Add a new definition in two ways: double-click the field and type `"QT += xml"`, or click the edit button on the right and add through that interface
5. Click **Apply** and close the window
6. Rebuild your project, and navigate to `/nbproject` and open your respective .pro file (debug or release)
7. Verify the new qmake entry is present